# Succeeding Bloc are not working after latest Bloc migration

Tags: flutter, bloc

I am using a MultiBlocProvider which is working for all Bloc before I migrate it to v8.0.1. Now, only the first Bloc (SignInBloc) is working.
This is on my main.dart

```
            return MultiBlocProvider(
              providers: [
                BlocProvider<SignInBloc>(
                  create: (context) => SignInBloc(
                    authenticationRepository: authenticationRepository,
                    userDataRepository: userDataRepository,
                  ),
                ),
                BlocProvider<SignUpBloc>(
                  create: (context) => SignUpBloc(
                    authenticationRepository: authenticationRepository,
                    userDataRepository: userDataRepository,
                  ),
                ),
```

Edit: here is my SignInBloc

```
  SignInBloc(
      {required this.authenticationRepository,
      required this.userDataRepository})
      : super(SignInInitialState()) {
    on<CheckIfSignedInEvent>(mapCheckIfSignedInEventToState);
  }

  Future<void> mapCheckIfSignedInEventToState(
    CheckIfSignedInEvent event,
    Emitter<SignInState> emit,
  ) async {
    try {
      bool isSignedIn = await authenticationRepository.checkIfSignedIn();
      if (isSignedIn) {
        emit(CheckIfSignedInEventCompletedState(true));
      } else {
        emit(CheckIfSignedInEventCompletedState(false));
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      emit(CheckIfSignedInEventFailedState());
    }
  }
```

I am not sure what to show but here is my SignUpBloc which is similar to my SignInBloc

```
  SignUpBloc(
      {required this.authenticationRepository,
      required this.userDataRepository})
      : super(SignUpInitialState()) {
    on<SignUpWithGoogle>(mapSignUpWithGoogleEventToState);
  }

  Stream<SignUpState> mapSignUpWithGoogleEventToState(
    SignUpWithGoogle event,
    Emitter<SignUpState> emit,
  ) async* {
    emit(SignUpInProgressState());

    try {
      User? checkUser = await authenticationRepository.checkIfUserExists();

      if (checkUser != null) {
        emit(SignUpWithGoogleInitialExistState());
      } else {
        bool checkDup =
            await authenticationRepository.checkIfUserDup(event.name);

        if (checkDup == true) {
          emit(SignUpWithNameExistState());
        } else {
          User firebaseUser = await authenticationRepository.signUpWithGoogle();
          emit(SignUpWithGoogleInitialCompletedState(firebaseUser));
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      emit(SignUpWithGoogleInitialFailedState());
    }
  }
```

My main.dart will call the splash screen which has the declaration of the bloc

```
late SignInBloc signInBloc;
late SignUpBloc signupBloc;

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    signInBloc = BlocProvider.of<SignInBloc>(context);
    signupBloc = BlocProvider.of<SignUpBloc>(context);
```

What I tried to do it to put alot of Print statement in order to check which part is getting called but I don't get why the SignUpBloc is not getting called anymore. Please help. Thanks!

Edit: I tried to debug.
This will trigger my SignInBloc. I'm able to listen to my SignInBloc.

```
signInBloc.add(CheckIfSignedInEvent());
```

This should trigger my SignUpBloc. But it doesn't do anything similar to my SignInBloc.

```
signupBloc.add(SignUpWithGoogle(name: selectedName));
```

Here's both of my events for comparison:

```
class CheckIfSignedInEvent extends SignInEvent {
  @override
  String toString() => 'CheckIfSignedInEvent';
}
```

```
class SignUpWithGoogle extends SignUpEvent {
  final String name;

  SignUpWithGoogle({required this.name});

  @override
  String toString() => 'SignUpWithGoogleEvent';
}
```

This is the part where I listen to the states which is both in my splash screen. Only signInBloc is able to listen.

```
    signupBloc.stream.listen((state) {
      print('BLOC: signupBloc splash screen init : $state');
    });

    signInBloc.stream.listen((state) {
      print('BLOC: signinBloc splash screen init : $state');
    });
```

Comment: What do you exactly mean by SignUpBloc isnt working? When do you want to call it? What happens in the debugger if you set a breakpoint in the last line of initState?

Comment: Hi, thank you for the idea. I haven't tried to debug before but I will do that now. For the other details that you're asking, I will update the code I have added above.

Comment: I have added more info after I debug. I don't really understand why my SignUpBloc is not working anymore. Note also that this started to behave wrong after I migrate to latest version of Bloc.

Comment: Have you tried using context? Like context.read<SignInBloc>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that changing the Stream to Future will fix my issue. async* should also be changed to async

```
Future<void> mapSignUpWithGoogleEventToState(
    SignUpWithGoogle event,
    Emitter<SignUpState> emit,
  ) async {
    emit(SignUpInProgressState());

    try {
      User? checkUser = await authenticationRepository.checkIfUserExists();

      if (checkUser != null) {
        emit(SignUpWithGoogleInitialExistState());
      } else {
        bool checkDup =
            await authenticationRepository.checkIfUserDup(event.name);

        if (checkDup == true) {
          emit(SignUpWithNameExistState());
        } else {
          User firebaseUser = await authenticationRepository.signUpWithGoogle();
          emit(SignUpWithGoogleInitialCompletedState(firebaseUser));
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      emit(SignUpWithGoogleInitialFailedState());
    }
  }
```